# Assign values of python DataFrame to variable

Tags: python, dataframe, variables, variable-assignment, trading

I have a python DataFrame than looks like this
[Dataframe Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Phr1.png)

I want to store tradingsymbol, overnight_quantity and average_price from each row to different variables to subsequently create code based on these variables. The number of rows can vary and is not fixed. Can someone please help to store these values of DataFrame into different variables?

i have tried using while loops. I am able to print the values iteratively but I am unable to store them into separate variables.

Comment: Do you want to have a variable containing all the values of `tradingsymbol` or just a single value and you then want to iterate across each row and do something? What is it you want to do exactly? It's generally very inefficient to loop over the rows. Pandas has a lot of ways to operate on the columns without needing a loop.

Comment: for each row, i want to assign a variables  for tradingsymbol , overnight_quantity and average_price. Say for example the dataframe has 10 rows, I want variables like tradingsymbol_1 to tradingsymbol_10; overnight_quantity_1 to overnight_quantity_10 and average_price_1 to average_price_10   Thanks

Comment: @Colin inefficiency in looping over rows isn't a concern as the maximum number that I am looking at is 10 rows

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.